# Problem with less than symbol and set variable lookup

Tags: workflow-lookup

Can some one confirm this is an issue?
Take a list and put a record in it with 2 records the data:

A<

A<B

Create a workflow that: Uses Set Variable action.

Set a string variable to the record ID when the title equals A<
This should succeed when the workflow runs.

Then try.
Set a string variable to the record ID when the title equals A<B
This fails.

I ran into this when I had data with name <name@place.com>.
I began to pick it apart and found if I eliminated the less than symbol it worked.

Comment: When you say it fails, do you mean there's an error or that it doesn't return a value?

Comment: I mean the ID value should be two and it returns ID equals zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the `<` is an html character. Looking for the record where `Title = A&lt;B` would return the record where your title equals `A<B`.

Comment: So my mistake was I essentially thought I was just dealing with strictly with ASCII characters and that's not quite the case.  I also tested this with the Regex match and a query and they both succeeded without adjustment.

Comment: Right; it's using html, not straight ASCII